# Авторизация через ЕСИА методом OpenConnect1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Добрый день! 
Хотел реализовать на сайте авторизацию через ЕСИА gри помощи OpenConnect . В свою очередь создал сертификат при помощи OPENSLL и отправил. Мне сертификат подтвердили. 
 В тестовых ключах имеются закрытые ключи. А созданный мною сертификат *.p12 не имеет файла с закрытыми ключами.
*Вопрос:* Как мне получить этот закрытый ключ? Для того чтоб подписывать запрос для отправки.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны были создать закрытый ключ когда создавали сертификат при помощи OpenSSL. Поищите его в своих файлах. Если вы его удалили - поздравляю, вам все делать заново.

Answer (score 1):

Ну Pavel Mayorov верно ответил. Добавлю, что нужно будет подавать заявку на "изменение параметров подключения к тестовой/промышленной" ЕСИА. Бланк заявки тут запросите: http://esia.pro/blanki_zayavok пришлют актуальную версию по регламенту. Только укажите, что вам нужна именно на переподключение и тип организации: гос./коммерс.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за комментарии!Сертификат *.p12 включает всебя закрытый ключ.
Средствами dotnet есть возможность подписать запрос
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(string fileName, string password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags).